# Error Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle' uploading to production server

Tags: php, symfony

I've just looked to other questions but I haven't found a solution to my problem.

I've developed my application on localhost and now I've uploaded it to production server but I get the error "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle' ".

My entity class starts with

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

  /**
   * @ORM\Entity
   * @ORM\Table(name="album")
   */
  class Album {
```

The config.yml

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

And in my controller I'm trying to access data using:

```
$albums = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Album')
            ->findAll();
```

I hope that someone can help me!

Thanks to everyone!!

Comment: Everything looks right... Did You clear cache ? `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Solved launching your command after deleting the database, next recreated the database with php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force now it works properly